# Changing the From name in outlook programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I have the following code

```
public void SendMail2(string subject, string body, string emailAddress)
{
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Subject = subject;
        mailItem.To = emailAddress;
        mailItem.Body = body;
        mailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Some Name Already Setup";
        mailItem.Display(false);
}
```

But when I call the method in my program, I receive the email myself instead of the intended recipient. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SentOnBehalfOfName` will only work when sending through Exchange. It should contain the name of another Exchange user on who's behalf the current user can send.

When sending through SMTP, set the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property instead.

Comment: I can not use smtp because of size constraints. I am using exchange but i am quite a noob at this, I have the other name setup to my account, but i can not figure out how to make the sender appear as that account

Comment: SentOnBehalfOfName  should work fien as long as you have the appropriate permissions. What is the value of the emailAddress variable?

Comment: it's the recipients email address as a string

Comment: So to is set to recipient's email address yet the message is received in you Inbox?

Comment: I just had the send() method missing, sorry for the silly mistake, it's all good now, other than its not displaying the html properly, it's just taking the body as text